# How can I make a clickable text that sends you to a hyperlink?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to build a command that sends a tellraw message in chat, and when this is clicked, it sends you to a link.

This is the link I want it to send to: `p.finsgraphics.com/15pVO`

And this is the tellraw I want it to show: `&f&lInFinite 16x &8&l1.9 3D &6&l[V1] &f&lDownload Link: &fp.finsgraphics.com/15pVO`

I cannot change the default resource pack due to the fact my server is hosted on ANOTHER Minecraft server.

So, what I need is user clicks a sign, tellraw shows in chat, click tellraw, and send you to link.

Is this possible? How can I do it?

Comment: Anybody? Please help!

Comment: Timelord64, why is it -1? This is my first post by the way.

Comment: The -1 (called a downvote) is because your question is not worded very well, and is difficult to answer. If you can edit your question to be more concise, it may get upvoted (+1) instead. For now, it's quite difficult to understand what you're asking exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a link to text in a `tellraw` command, add a `"clickEvent"` object to each of the objects in your JSON of the tellraw. Then add a `"action":"open_url"` and a `"value":"URL_HERE"` value to each of the `"clickEvent"` objects, replacing `URL_HERE` with the url you want. So in the end it will look something like this:

```
/tellraw @p [{"text":"TEXT","clickEvent":{"action":"open_url","value":"http://example.com/"}}]
```

I ran your text through a [tellraw generator](http://commandfox.js.org/tellraw.html), and [added the `clickEvent` object with the values to it](https://jsfiddle.net/grsj7yu1/). Here is your command:

```
/tellraw @p [{"color":"white","bold":true,"text":"InFinite 16x ","clickEvent":{"action":"open_url","value":"http://p.finsgraphics.com/15pVO"}},{"bold":true,"color":"dark_gray","text":"1.9 3D ","clickEvent":{"action":"open_url","value":"http://p.finsgraphics.com/15pVO"}},{"bold":true,"color":"gold","text":"[V1] ","clickEvent":{"action":"open_url","value":"http://p.finsgraphics.com/15pVO"}},{"bold":true,"color":"white","text":"Download Link: ","clickEvent":{"action":"open_url","value":"http://p.finsgraphics.com/15pVO"}},{"bold":false,"color":"white","text":"p.finsgraphics.com/15pVO","clickEvent":{"action":"open_url","value":"http://p.finsgraphics.com/15pVO"}}]
```

Comment: this really helped. i copied it then pasted, next filling in the things like the example.com thing and the TEXT thing. thank you!